# Triac Switch Circuit using MOC3021 and BT136

Tags: power-electronics, opto-isolator, triac, snubber

I am tinkering with BT136 & MOC3021 optocoupler to control AC loads, and below is the schematic i have put together. I have a few doubts here.

1. Is the value of 100 ohm 1 watt correct on pin 6 of MOC3021
2. Is 50 ohm, 1 watt sufficient in snubber circuit.
3. Is 10 nF, 250 V sufficient or should I use 400 V.
4. Any other design issues / sugesstions for improvement.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Is the value of 100 ohm 1 watt correct on pin 6 of MOC3021

[image]

*Figure 1. The [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/97984.pdf) suggests this circuit.*

Remember that when the MOC triac is off that there is no current through your R16 so no power will be dissipated. When the MOC turns on there will be a very brief current through R16 but Q4 will turn on almost instantly and the voltage across the circuit will drop close to zero. The power dissipated in R16 will be very low.

According to the datasheet you can increase your R16 value. The datasheet circuit includes a low-pass filter (the two resistors and capacitor) to improve noise immunity. You'll probably be OK with your simpler circuit.

> 2. Is 50 ohm, 1 watt sufficient in snubber circuit.

The approach here is to work out the worst-case current through C7.

\$ Z_C = \frac 1 {2 \pi f C} = 318\ \text k \Omega \$ at 50 Hz.

\$ I_C = \frac V Z = \frac {250}{318k} = 0.8 \ \text {mA}\$.

\$ P_{R15} = I^2 R = (0.8 \times 10^{-3})^2 \times 50 = 32 \ \mu \text W\$. Do you think 1 W might be a little over-cautious?

> 3. Is 10 nF, 250 V sufficient or should I use 400 V.

250 V<sub>RMS</sub> peaks at 250√2 = 353 V. You need 400 V rating.

> 4. Any other design issues / sugesstions for improvement.

Just be aware that the opto-isolator you have chosen is a "random-phase" type as opposed to a zero-cross type. I have written about them on [Opto-triacs, solid-state relays (SSR), zero-cross and how they work](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/).

**Links**

- [Phase Control Using Thyristors](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/application_notes/switching_thyristors/littelfuse_thyristor_phase_control_using_thyristors_application_note.pdf.pdf) by Littlefuse.
- [Thyristor Theory and Design Considerations Handbook](http://www.icbase.com/File/News/download/ON_Reference_1.PDF)
   by ON Semiconductor.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I was now thinking if i need snubber circuit at all ?. Can i get away without R15 & C7

Comment: Read the links I've added for more on the importance of snubbers.

Comment: thank you for the details, i have updated the schematic to match your suggestion.

Comment: what is waveform of load ? when Data/IO/Pin2 is high? pure sine or trimmed sine?

Comment: Re-read the paragraph before the Links section.

Comment: I can add that resistor in series with TRIAC gate is responsible for smallest turn-on voltage. If it is too big, TRIAC will not be able to turn on at low voltages due to its finite gate trigger current. This limits smallest phase angle and increases EMI in general. Smallest acceptable value is limited by maximum gate current and maximum optocoupler current, as Marko Buršič wrote.
Another factor, resistors have limited rated voltage. Consult datasheet of yours. With leaded resistors and 220 V, at least 0,25 W is recommended, 0,5 W is best of all.

Comment: What would be the voltage rating of 0.05uF capacitor in this circuit? Will a 100V rated capacitor work without any issue? I checked the datasheet given in the link but there is nothing about voltage rating.

Comment: @San, consider when the MOC is off that the load will be a low impedance so there will be full mains voltage across it. That means it must be rated for the mains and that it must be AC rated. Apply a factor of safety too!

Answer (score 1):

Peak Repetitive Surge Current = \$\dfrac{220V\cdot\sqrt{2}}{100\Omega}=3.1 > 1A (MOC3021)\$

So the 100 ohm is to low.

Comment: How much should that be? 1k/10k/100k etc. my hits and tries works with 560ohm 1/4w but I am not sure if that will fry it later..